# Classic cipher method

Tags: classical-cipher

I am struggling with these two cipher texts, I cannot identify which king of cipher was used.
First:
otnpeetrnneepeufofutisrtrllohcdmetoeheeatyngonrmrm
And second:
mvevgpwosytaeeisvcgofotbisfnoamtersmeslykuoakaypep